# Jquery Mobile - edit side-bar on load

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I want to insert the name and picture to the side-bar dynamically. I tried this way but it works only for the first page and after navigation to another page, the span and the img tags are both empty:

Jquery:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function(e) {
       $("#nameFB").text("test");
       $('#imgFB').attr('src', 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + fb_id + '/picture');
       $('#nav-panel').trigger('create');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="home" data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel" >
      <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
            <a href="#nav-panel" data-iconpos="notext" id="sidebar" data-icon="custom"></a>
      </div>
      <div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="false" data-display="reveal" id="nav-panel">
            <a href="Profile.html" data-role="button"  id="profile">
                   <img src="" id="imgFB"/><span id="nameFB"></span>  </a><br/>
            <a href="Notifications.html" data-role="button"  > Notifications </a><br/>
      </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: If you want the same panel across multiple pages, you might want to just define a single external panel (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/panel-external/) otherwise, with a panel in each page, you should have unique IDs or access the panel elements as children of the active page...

Comment: thanks! how can i access the children of the active page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6cmG7/ use $.mobile.activePage